# Save multiple datasets to different variables using a loop

Tags: python, numpy, variables, while-loop, loaddata

I have to load in 7 datasets and want to assign the data in each to separate variables. I have included my loop below. Right now, it works but it loads all the datasets into variable_name as 7 indices when I want it to output each variable separately given the names in the variable_name list.

```
dir = '/data/watkinson/Model_and_Inversion_Code/indiv_variables_output/'
file_name = ['mld_field','sp_field','lp_field','tmp_field','pz_field','sz_field','lz_field']
mld,sp,lp,temp,pz,sz,lz = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
variable_name = [mld,sp,lp,temp,pz,sz,lz]
i=0
while i < 7:
     variable_name[i] = np.array(nc.Dataset(dir + file_name[i] + '.nc', 'r').variables[file_name[i]][:, :, :, :],dtype=float)
     i += 1
```

Comment: You have 7 files. You want to load the data from each file into a list where df_list = [df1, df2, df3,.... df7] where each of them is a dataframe. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have 3 files:

```
filename: abc.csv:

Name,Age,Sex
Joey,10,M
Kate,12,F
Mike,14,M
Jane,11,F
Abby,12,F

filename: xyz.csv:

City,State
San Francisco,CA
Chicago,IL
Buffalo,NY
Atlanta,GA
Miami,FL

filename:pqr.csv:

Company,Product
Tesla,Model X
Tesla,Model Y
Apple,MacBook Pro
Ford,Mustang
```

Then you can give something like this to get all the 3 files stored as a dataframe into a list.

```
import pandas as pd
files = ['abc.csv','xyz.csv','pqr.csv']
dfs = []
for f in files:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(f))
print (dfs)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[   Name  Age Sex
0  Joey   10   M
1  Kate   12   F
2  Mike   14   M
3  Jane   11   F
4  Abby   12   F,             

            City State
0  San Francisco    CA
1        Chicago    IL
2        Buffalo    NY
3        Atlanta    GA
4          Miami    FL,   

  Company      Product
0   Tesla      Model X
1   Tesla      Model Y
2   Apple  MacBook Pro
3    Ford      Mustang]
```

In your case, you can just iterate through `file_name` and you don't need to have the index value.

```
file_name = ['mld_field','sp_field','lp_field','tmp_field','pz_field','sz_field','lz_field']
```

Just give:

```
for file in file_name:
    variable_name.append(....)
```

here you can give pd.read_csv(file) inside the append.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which will give you your `i` index counting from 0 along with your variable names.

### With hard index `i`

```
dir = '/data/watkinson/Model_and_Inversion_Code/indiv_variables_output/'
file_name = ['mld_field','sp_field','lp_field','tmp_field','pz_field','sz_field','lz_field']
variable_names = ['mld','sp','lp','temp','pz','sz','lz']
variable_data = {}
for i, name in enumerate(variable_names):
    variable_data[name] = np.array(nc.Dataset(dir + file_name[i] + '.nc', 'r').variables[file_name[i]][:, :, :, :],dtype=float)
```

You can access each variable separately:

```
print(variable_data['mld'])
print(variable_data['sp'])
...
```

### Without hard index `i`

I try to avoid using hard indices `i` where possible.  Here we use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to replace enumerate:

```
dir = '/data/watkinson/Model_and_Inversion_Code/indiv_variables_output/'
file_name = ['mld_field','sp_field','lp_field','tmp_field','pz_field','sz_field','lz_field']
variable_names = ['mld','sp','lp','temp','pz','sz','lz']
variable_data = {}
for filename, name in zip(file_names, variable_names):
    variable_data[name] = np.array(nc.Dataset(dir + file_name + '.nc', 'r').variables[file_name][:, :, :, :],dtype=float)
```